# How to avoid Error 404 when trying to access statically generated links -- next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js, hyperlink

I am building a small project in Next.js where I am making a statically generated online library website. When a user clicks on a link (a book in this case) they are taken to another page where they can access more details about the book. However, when testing my links, I get a Page Not Found Error (404). I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

My code -

```js
import { getBooks, BookPages } from "@/lib/extractPaths";
import getData from "@/lib/extractData";
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps, NextPage } from "next";
import { NextParsedUrlQuery } from "next/dist/server/request-meta";

interface BookPage {
  bookData: BookPages[]; // contains book name and author
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const bookPath = await getBooks(); // contains book id, name, author, title and its path which is to be used by getStaticPaths

  var paths: string[] = bookPath.map((data) => {
    return data.pathTitle;
  });

  const pathTitles = [];

  console.log(paths);

  for (let path of paths) {
    pathTitles.push({ params: { path } }); // storing paths in the format getStaticPaths expects it [params: {...}, params: {...},]
  }

  console.log(pathTitles);

  return {
    paths: pathTitles,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const bookData = await getBooks();
  return {
    props: { bookData },
  };
};

const ClickedBook: NextPage<BookPage> = ({ bookData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>bookData.title</h1>
      <h3>bookData.author</h3>
      {/*may add some more information about books later on*/}
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore velit
        omnis voluptas cupiditate saepe fugit dicta iure beatae, maxime
        explicabo? Nam officia explicabo animi repellendus deserunt aliquid sunt
        facere facilis?
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClickedBook;
```

I wish to know what about my code makes the links not work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**PS**: I am an absolute noob and I am aware my code can be improved in a million different ways already. I am just trying to learn as much as I can :).